# Powershell Scripting for multiple Entries updating According to current time

Tags: powershell, scripting, multiple-entries

I am having some information in the text file. I have to fetch that content regularly and run the script every time to eliminate the past entries based on the current time. I have to match the entries with the current time and have to delete the whole entry that has past time in it. I don't want to remove the entries in the future time. Mentioning the entries down.

```
[MyFirstEntry_abc.hostname.address]
Name=Abc
Class=5
Section=A
hostname= First Host
Time = hh:mm:ss DD:MM:YYYY +11:00
```

Now if Time is in the future I want to keep the entry and if Time is in the Past I want to delete the entry in the file and the remaining entry should remain intact.
I have considered the case of having N entries in the text file. Can you please help me to remove the past entries as I am not able able to match the entries and del them in the text file?

Comment: Cool, sounds like you know what needs to be done :) What's the question?

Comment: See the PowerShell help files/Examples for [Get-Content, Select-String or RegEx, -Replace, If/Then or Try/Catch, Get-Date, TimeSpan, comparison operators, ForEach, Loops].   SO rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)